# VPN Client - Cisco - Cisco Systems on Windows

Tags: windows-7, vpn, cisco-vpn-client

Does anyone know a good and free VPN client that runs on Windows 7 (Premium)?

I've tried the Windows' built-in tool. But it didn't work. This is what I did: go to Network and Sharing Center choose setup new Connection choose VPN, and enter the server's IP click 'OK' to connect.

The thing fails. So I right-click on the connection just created, go to properties, in security tab, I set the VPN type to ipsec. Then I clicked on Advanced settings, and supply the preshared key. This should work, right???? Well, it didn't.

I dont know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am under the impression that you need the Cisco VPN Client in order to connect to a Cisco VPN on Windows.

http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/sw/secursw/ps2308/index.html

From what I recall it was easy to setup, the only thing I remember with it was that it was not a free download, but something that I got from the VPN provider.

The options to get it Cisco gives is:

```
Here are instructions for downloading the Cisco VPN Client:

If you have a SMARTnet support contract and encryption entitlement, download the free Cisco VPN Client.
If you do not have a SMARTnet support contract and encryption entitlement, get the Cisco VPN Client on CD from your reseller. Use the Partner Locator to find a reseller.
If you don't know, ask your IT department whether they already have the Cisco VPN Client.
```

And if those 3 options means nothing to you I suggest you contact whoever is running the VPN Server you are trying to connect to.

So the Cisco Client is free in some cases and might cost money in other - The Cisco VPN Client is included with Cisco ASA 5500 Series Adaptive Security Appliances (except ASA 5505)

Comment: Why did  @studiohack close my question??????? It's toally a REAL question!!!

Comment: Not sure, but I think that your question was a bit unclear on what you were asking for ... might also have been seen as "issues specific to corporate IT support and networks", but for instance playing with Ciso for a certification isn't IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that you will need to utilize a [Cisco VPN client](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/ps10884/index.html) in order to connect to a Cisco VPN. On Windows 7, you will also need to modify the preferences file set EnableNAT to true (or 1).

If the VPN you're trying to connect to is setup in a Windows Server role (or other non Cisco type of VPN), then you can try using [Shrew VPN client](http://www.shrew.net/software).

If you do not have a VPN setup at all, and are looking to get such a network setup for personal use, then look into [Hamachi](https://secure.logmein.com/products/hamachi/). I believe for non-corporate use, you can setup this client on up to 10 computers and it will remain free to use.

Comment: You can use Shrew for Cisco VPNs as well, so long as you have the .pcf files from your organization's Cisco VPN Client installer.

Comment: @Iszi Good to know, thanks! I was unsure if Shrew had the ability to import PCF's as of yet.